# How can I recreate this JSON array in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array in **JSON** that I need to recreate in **PHP**.

```
         {
            "items": {
              "category": "fruit",
              "detail": [
                {
                  "name": "apple",
                  "good": true
                }
              ]
            }
            "moreItems": {
              "category": "fruit",
              "detail": [
                {
                  "name": "banana",
                  "good": false
                }
              ]
            }
        }
```

My hopes are to create this using **PHP** arrays, then **json_encode** it.
I've tried to set the array above to a string, and de_coded it, but I'm not getting anywhere.

Thanks.

Comment: Please show the array that you attempted to create.

Comment: what's your expected outcome?

Comment: Just create an array with the same structure and encode it. Don't really see the problem here?

Comment: @anantkumarsingh I'm trying to create the array above with PHP

Comment: You know how to define an array right? If not: https://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php. You could literally copy&paste this, replace all `:` with `=>` and all `{...}` with `[...]` and you are done.

Comment: @FelixKling I got confused because surely the sub contents of "items": {} is an array, yet "detail": [] has square brackets. Are these different types of arrays?

Comment: `{}` in JavaScript is an _object_ not an _array_. JS (and therefore JSON) arrays (`[]` square) have strictly ascending numeric keys, unlike PHP where they may have associative string keys or a mix of both.  So all of that can translate to PHP arrays, wherein the `[]` have numeric keys and the `{}` maintain the same string properties as in the JSON

Comment: Okay let me give it ago given the new information.

Comment: Oh, I see where you may be confused - the `details` key has `[]` surrounding `{}`. That would mean it is nested as an assoc array inside a 1 element numeric array like like `'detail' => array(0 => array('name' => 'banana', 'good' => false))`\

Comment: is detail a multi-dimensional array? it seems so, from your code. Also items and moreItems are not separated with coma.

Comment: @pinkalvansia It would appear so

Comment: If you want to replicate the structure more truly, forcing PHP to use `stdClass` objects instead of assoc arrays, you might cast the inner ones to objects:  `'detail' => array(0 => (object)array('name' => 'banana', 'good' => false))`

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski I don't need it to replicate that truthfully, although that's useful to note for the future. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in PHP

```
$arr = array("items" => array(
                  0 => array (
                     "category" => "fruit",
                     "detail" => array("name" => "apple", "good" => true )
                     )
                 ),
             "moreItems" => array( 
                  0 => array (
                     "category" => "fruit",
                     "detail" => array("name" => "banana", "good" => false)
                     )
                 )
            );
```

or for manual assignment that maybe useful if using loops:

```
$arr["items"]["category"] = "fruit";
$arr["items"]["detail"][0]["name"] = "apple";
$arr["items"]["detail"][0]["good"] = true;

$arr["moreItems"]["category"] = "fruit";
$arr["moreItems"]["detail"][0]["name"] = "banana";
$arr["moreItems"]["detail"][0]["good"] = false;

echo json_encode($arr);
```

will give you the same output..

Actual output in JSON

[image]

Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

If you have a json (in PHP) as a string, and you want to convert them to a native PHP array you can easy do that:

```
<?php
    function objectToArray( $object )
    {
        if( !is_object( $object ) && !is_array( $object ) )
        {
            return $object;
        }
        if( is_object( $object ) )
        {
            $object = get_object_vars( $object );
        }
        return array_map( 'objectToArray', $object );
    }

    $json = '{\
        "items": {\
          "category": "fruit",\
          "detail": [\
            {\
              "name": "apple",\
              "good": true\
            }\
          ]\
        }\
        "moreItems": {\
          "category": "fruit",\
          "detail": [\
            {\
              "name": "banana",\
              "good": false\
            }\
          ]\
        }\
    }';

    $array = objectToArray( json_decode($json) );
    echo "<pre>".print_r($array, true)."</pre>";
```

That's it!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to **Michael Berkowski**, this worked for me. You can recreate the nested [] in the code below.

> If you want to replicate the structure more truly, forcing PHP to use
>   stdClass objects instead of assoc arrays, you might cast the inner
>   ones to objects: 'detail' => array(0 => (object)array('name' =>
>   'banana', 'good' => false))

This below will do just fine for me.

```
           $phpArray = array(
                "items" => array(
                    "category" => "fruit",
                    "detail" => array(
                        0 => array(
                            "name" => "apple", "good" => true
                        )
                    )
                ),
                "moreItems" => array(
                    "category" => "fruit",
                    "detail" => array(
                        0 => array(
                            "name" => "banana",
                            "good" => false
                        )
                    )
                )
            );
```

Comment: I notice you don't really need the `0 =>` there. They are implicit in just using `array(array(... ))`